# How to instantiate from instantiated object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene I instantiate an Brick, this Brick have a script that instantiate an Enemy as child of it.

The problem is that the script of the instantiated Brick is not working, so the Enemy didn't instantiated, how to solve that?

**First script:**

```
public GameObject[] Bricks;

void SpawnBricks(int numCubes = 20, float startY = 3, float delta = 0.6f, float AngleDis = 3f)
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Bricks.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i)
    {
        var Brick = Instantiate(Bricks[Rand], new Vector3(0, startY - (float)i * delta, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Brick.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

**Brick Script:**

```
public GameObject[] Enemies;

public void Awake()
{
    SpawnTheEnemies();
}

public void SpawnTheEnemies()
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Enemies.Length);
    var Buildings = Instantiate(Enemies[Rand], transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, Random.Range(0, 360), 0));
        Buildings.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the error, your code and what you have tried so far

Comment: Only your script will help us in helping you.

Comment: @Guilherme Please check the answer

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanAqeel Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is inside the awake function. When your Brick gets spawned, it doesn't contain any element inside Enemies array. 
You may want to assign Enemies reference inside the array before using SpawnTheEnemies function.

### One possible solution.

```
public GameObject[] Enemies;

public void Awake()
{
Enemies = FindObjectsOfType<[YourEnemyScriptName]>(); // Insert your Enemies script name inside [].
}

void Start(){
    SpawnTheEnemies();
}

public void SpawnTheEnemies()
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, Enemies.Length);
    GameObject Buildings = Instantiate(Enemies[Rand], transform.position,         Quaternion.Euler(0, Random.Range(0, 360), 0));
        Buildings.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't instantiate the enemies, but why the spawned bricks didn't contain any element inside Enemies array?

Comment: If your brick is a prefab, are you putting reference of enemies from the inspector?